# Is there any way to set the auto-generated document id to a doc field called id?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using firebase, anguarfire2 and i want when i create a new document in a collection, the generated id to be saved also in a field called id? Is that possible?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981537/5246885) out.

Comment: I was thinking about a solution. Call the function to create the document with the fields i want and then get a snapshot to the current document in order to get the id. Then use set method to update the document. What do you think? @AlexMamo

Comment: Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470538/angular-firebase-firestore-get-document-id) out.

Answer (score 0):

The approach and syntax for the Firebase Javascript library is as below. It should almost same for AngularFire2.

```js
const docRef = await firestore()
    .collection("some-collecton")
    .doc();
  await docRef.set({ id: docRef.id, ...otherDocumentData });
```